# Scala - How to parse DateTime to a custom format with ISODateTimeFormat?

Tags: scala, date, datetime, jodatime

I wanted to parse a `joda.time.DateTime` with `ISODateTimeFormat` to the following format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` having `HH:mm:ss` truncated to all zeros. I've partially achieved the goal using withTimeAtStartOfDay.

The below code results in `2019-11-28T00:00:00.000+03:00` instead of `2019-11-28 00:00:00`

```
val dateTime: DateTime = new DateTime().minusDays(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay
```

Am I correct that that it's not possible to achieve this with `ISODateTimeFormat`? 
I've tried to use `DateTimeFormat` and it worked but want to understand if there is a better approach.

```
val timeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    println(dateTime.toString(timeFormatter)) // 2019-11-28 00:00:00
```

Comment: Are you forced to use `joda.time`? It's rather outdated.

Comment: @jwvh I've also tried `java.time` and it worked ok. But decided to experiment with `joda.time` as well. What would you recommend as a good choice in this case?

Comment: `dateTime` is a `DateTime` object. How does it "result in 2019-11-28T00:00:00.000+03:00" ? Did you call `toString` on it? Please show how you used `ISODateTimeFormat` to arrive at that output.

Comment: @Thilo: that's not surprising since JodaTime's `DateTime` has Timezone information, and if you format that in ISO format, that is what you will get.

Comment: Sure. But if you want to have a custom format without timezone information, you can specify such a formatter (even using Joda --- which I agree is an outdated approach). I just wanted to confirm that this was done properly (especially since from skimming the Javadoc for ISODateTimeFormat it is not obvious to me where it can be configured to not include the timezone fields).

Comment: @samba All other things being equal I would go with the advice from [The Joda-Time home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/): *Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you really should no longer use JodaTime, just use the classes from `java.time` (JodaTime was integrated into Java 8).

Second, you basically just want to handle dates. Then you could simply use a `LocalDate` and just output a fixed text portion in your format since you know that it always will be "00:00:00":

```scala
import java.time._
import java.time.format._

val yesterday = LocalDate.now.minusDays(1)

println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(yesterday) + " 00:00:00")
```